# User permission and executing adb from php

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, permissions

I am trying to run adb from PHP using:

```
exec( 'adb devices', $output, $return_val );
```

but I get 126 error.

I think the problem is that php is running as 'www-data' user and does not have permissions to execute adb.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This page](http://www.museum.state.il.us/ismdepts/library/linuxguides/abs-guide/exitcodes.html) shows that this error code means a permission problem or the program can not be executed.

If your program is executable (have `x` permission), you need to make sure it can be executed by www-data user.

If it requires super user privilege, you need to setup sudo without password for www-data to execute this command. You need to edit sudoers file using `sudo visudo`. Then, add a line like:

```
www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/program
```

To run a command as different user, you can use the form:

```
sudo -u username command
```

Comment: The program that I am trying to run is adb for Android and I have allready added it to the `Path=` for the current user. When I run `adb devices` is working just fine while`sudo adb devices` it is not working as it cannot find adb. Can I just add `www-data` to execute files as the current user and not root? is that possible? or should I add `adb` to the environment variable for super users?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I would like to ask if its risky to add www-data to sudoers?

Comment: It depends on the privileges you are granting. If you are granting a specific the privilege to execute a single unrisky program, it should be fine.